# how to make php blenc work on wampserver?

Tags: php, encryption, wamp, wampserver, php-extension

I would like to ask about how can I use PHP Blenc on wampserver? I've followed every instructions in here but I got an error saying the PHP Blenc function were undefined

http://www.php.net//manual/en/book.blenc.php

I am using PHP 5.4.12 on 64-bit (so as my wampserver architecture I guess). I also tried the example scripts from above and an undefined function is what I get.

The package can be found here

http://www.php.net//manual/en/book.blenc.php

I've searched through the net and always got redirected to the php.net manual.

I am very grateful if someone can give me a detailed instruction on how to make this PHP Blenc work to encrypt my script

Thank you in advance :-)

Answer (score 0):

I dont see a PHP5.4 64bit option in the download area. So that probably means you have downloaded blenc for PHP5.5 64bit or blenc for PHP5.4 32bit.

Either way its not going to run.

You are either going to have to use the 32bit WAMPServer (Apache/PHP/MySQL) so you can stay on PHP5.4 or upgrade your PHP version to PHP5.5.x so you can stick with 64bit and get a blenc extension that will work.

To be honest, there is no great benefit to using the 64bit WAMPServer and quite a few benefits, like having access to some of the more esoteric PHP extensions, in using the 32bit.
In fact 64bit PHP is still considered 'Experimental' and has not yet been fully converted to 64bit anyway.